# Getting arguments[0].setAttribute is not a function error in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am using the below code to highlight the input box in a web page:

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
WebElement username= driver.findElement(By.id("email"));  
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','border: solid 2px 
red');", username);
```

It is giving me an error like this:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebdriverException: unknown error: 
arguments[0].setAttribute is not a function
```

Note: The tag in the web page already has a style attribute in it.

Comment: Any reason to use `JavascriptExecutor` and not `Java` functions?

Answer (score 1):

I think your syntax is wrong, you forget to add ''quotes near style and also remove ; before username

try this code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
WebElement username= driver.findElement(By.id("email")); 
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','border: solid 2px red')", username)
```

Comment: No your answer did not help...typo was here in SO not in my code

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes, please try the following code,

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
WebElement username= driver.findElement(By.id("email"));  
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','border: solid 2px red');", username);
```

Comment: After adding the missing quote also getting the same error. @Murthi

Comment: alternatively, you can try arguments[0].style.border='solid 2px red';